# How can I use a singleton model to manage CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, core-bluetooth

Okay, I have been checking out the singleton model for the past couple of days and I find that the singleton model is exactly what I need to implement to manage bluetooth for my current app.
I put in the central manager and peripheral functions from the CoreBluetooth API in the singleton that I defined. When I tried to call the function from my viewController, I kept getting multiple errors like "Cannot invoke central manager with an argument list of type ((CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber).Type)

```
BlueCoreManager.shared.centralManager(CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
```

This was just one of the many errors I got. BlueCoreManager is my singleton in the above line.

So I did some more digging and found some outdated source code on github that used the singleton model for bluetooth management. What I saw was a singleton was defined for each function (Select Peripheral, Connect Peripheral, Read Peripheral etc) with a protocol defined for each one. Is this the best practice? I also need to write specific commands to multiple peripherals. Also, in the source code, I noticed that the coreBluetooth api functions were defined in the singleton but were never called directly. Will the functions be called automatically if I refer to the other functions in the singleton? Could someone shed some light on the best way to proceed?

Comment: The issue with your code is that you're calling directly the delegate method, that's not what you should do. Either you use NSNotification, either a custom delegate for your BlueCoreManager.

Comment: Awesome! I got it working, Thanks.

Comment: @Jobs please write down your solution if you r here, thanks.